# How to run Cg vertex/fragment shader on CPU?

Tags: cg, fragment-shader, vertex-shader

I'm playing about with some vertex and fragment shaders using Cg on my little netbook (running Linux). Clearly I'm going to frequently hit resource limits for my graphics controller, so was wondering if there's a nice way to run the shaders on the CPU, just to test them. Something like D3D's refrast...

TIA

Andy

Answer (score 0):

Opensource Opengl software Mesa has shader support : http://www.mesa3d.org/shading.html

Comment: Thanks for that, bit busy to look into it now, but look forward to checking it out when I have time!